# Unreliable DialogFragment layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have noticed that sometimes the `DialogFragment` is displayed horrendously. For example, given the following XML:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_large">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_medium"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_medium"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/Text.Subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a test with 'match_parent'"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/close" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It displays this:

[image]

On the other hand, the following XML is *broken*:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_large">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_medium"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_medium"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/Text.Subtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a test with '0dp'"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/close" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

I have only made these changes:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent" --> android:layout_width="0dp"
add --> app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

I have experienced this with other layouts (`LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`) as well. Why is this ?

I have seen many questions about settings the sizes of dialogs and I believe it's due to this *bug*. Most set new layout params in `onResume` but it feels hacky and I feel like there is an explanation.

Here the `DialogFragment` implementation used:

```kotlin
class SomeFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSomeBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentSomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is an attempt with `LinearLayout` with similar unexpected behaviour.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_large">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_medium"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_medium"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/Text.Subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a test with 'LinearLayout'"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but `match_parent` is not permitted in _ConstraintLayout_. See the boxed comment in [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout) regarding `match_parent`. I would avoid using it since we are warned off.

Comment: I did not know that, good point. I uploaded a new layout using `LinearLayout` instead. Any ideas why it behaves the way it does ?

Comment: I have to agree with @CommonsWare. Your layout is being placed into a window that has a width of `wrap_content` and you are not exercising any control over that width. You can look at the layout in an emulator using the Layout Inspector or simply wrap your layout in a _LinearLayout_ with a width of `wrap_content` to satisfy yourself that this is what is happening. Even with a _LinearLayout_, I still think that `match_parent` is an issue with the _TextView_ which should be `wrap_content` or given a specific size.

Comment: I did not manage to get any information on the parent or their attributes, but wrapping my layout with another one set to `android:width="wrap_content"` made me understand that the produced layout was the result of the _negotiated_ size between the parent and child layouts. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the following XML is broken

Both are broken.

Your `ConstraintLayout` has `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, and you have no control over the parent. The parent's width presumably is `wrap_content`, given your screenshots, but you should not be relying upon that, as it could vary. Either give the `ConstraintLayout` a specific width or use `wrap_content` for its width.

Comment: I don't understand what you imply saying I have no control over the parent. I edited the post and uploaded another example using `LinearLayout` to make things simpler. Do you see anything wrong with it ?

Comment: @JonZarate: "I don't understand what you imply saying I have no control over the parent" -- OK. Show me in your examples what the parent is of the `ConstraintLayout` and of the `LinearLayout`. You will find that you cannot do that, because you are not the one supplying that parent.

Comment: Cheticamp's comment helped me understand your answer and you are right. I did not know the parent `View` was set to `wrap_content`.